# required field validator

Tags: asp.net

i am new to asp.net and i am setting required field validator and it is showing me an error

**error is:**

```
Unable to find control id 'txtFirstName' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'RequiredFieldValidator1'.
```

**code is:**

```
 <tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-right: 5px; width: 50%;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="FIRSTNAME :"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFistName" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>

        </tr>
```

can any help me on this flow....,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in the id of `TextBox`, you have id `txtFistName` not `txtFirstName` so change it.

*Change*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFistName" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
```

*To*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I have changed the id of textbox from txtFistName  to txtFirstName as in TextBox you have txtFistName and in RequiredFieldValidator, ControlToValidate you have given txtFirstName

Comment: @BHARATH You should add the letter `r` in the ID field of the textbox.